# reactjs handles only the last api request data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-table

I have a react table with multiple functions like sort and many filters also search the input. When I make any changes on these filters, I am actually making an API request.
For every request made I have 2 states {i.e. loading and data}.
When a request is made the loading flag is changed to `TRUE` and the spinning component replaces the data in the table. When we start getting any response the loading flag will be `False`.

**The problem**:
When I change more than one filter,it will make multiple API calls/requests. The response will come back asynchronized and therefore the table starts showing the first response data,a few moments after showing the last response data.

**What I want to implement**: I want to ignore all the requests and handle only the last one.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem a while back similar to yours. I used a debouncing technique with the lodash library which worked out well.
The debounce function makes the request if there are no other pending
requests within a specified time (one second here)

```
import _ from "lodash";

     const debounce = useCallback(
          _.debounce(() => {
            // Call a function here to make the api request
            getData('yourApiUrl');
          }, 1000),
          []
        );
```

The [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook allows this function to update only when its dependencies change. Right now I am using an empty array but you could put any of your filter related state values in there.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(conditionToCall){
    debounce();
    return debounce.cancel;
  }
}, [lastFilter]);
```

In the useEffect above you can trigger this debounce function only when your flag is true and cancel the rest.
Now when it comes down to only passing the last filter to the api call one thing you could do is keep a useState hook which updates to the most current filter everytime one changes. And in a useEffect, update it to the current one like so:

```
const [lastfilter, setLastFilter] = useState('default');
useEffect(() => {
//set the state to whatever filter value gets triggered
setLastFilter(currentFilter);
//Remember to pass dependencies 
//to this array so it runs everytime a relevant
//piece of state updates.
}, [dependencies]);
```

An important thing to not is that I added my sample lastFilter hook into the useEffect dependency array for calling the debounce function. This allows it to run on every update for that value. With a combination of these things I hope you are able to move in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) property of react class lifecycle to get the latest updated data from state "data".

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
   ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It could simply be done using [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

- on every keystroke or input change, store the search text value in `useRef` variable.
- make the API call which would use the local "text value"
- once the API call returns the result for "text value" (async), update the state only if "text value" is matched against `useRef` value.  Indicating it's the latest result.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

// React Component that will be rendered onto the page
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [results, setResult] = useState("");
  const currentText = useRef("");

  // term is not shared amongst multiple invocations
  const handleChange = async (term) => {
    setText(term);
    currentText.current = term;
    if (term) {
      const res = await searchAPI(term);
      // update state only if it's the latest api cll
      if (currentText.current === term) {
        console.log("update from latest api call");
        setResult(res);
      } else {
        console.log("ignore old api call");
      }
    } else {
      setResult("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={text}
        placeholder="enter search term"
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div> results: {results}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```